# c++ does not throw error if accessing wrong index of string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have the code below:

```
string s = "haha";
cout << s << endl; //haha
cout << s.length() << endl; //4
cout << (s[25] == 'h' ? "is h" : "is not h") << endl; //is not h
cout << s[0] << endl; // h
cout << s[25] << endl; // nothing...blank
```

It seems that pointing to any index even if it is out of range does not throw any error...what is the reason?

Comment: C++ doesn't do any bounds checking on itself. You'll need to know what you're doing.

Comment: @PMF: It does, but only if you tell it to. Accessing an invalid index through `[]` is *undefined behaviour*. Which means the behaviour is not defined to give an error message, throw an exception, or crash the program. It *could*, but it doesn't have to, so implementations don't have to do the additional bounds check -- speeding things up. Accessing through `at()` *is* defined to throw an exception if the index is invalid.

Comment: To answer your question of "what is the reason" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Efficiency. You can use [at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) function for bounds check.

Answer (score 2):

Class `string` provides bound checking in [at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) function, it throws exception if the subscript is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::string::operator[]` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) says:

```
char& operator[] (size_t pos);
```

## Exception safety

If pos is not greater than the string length, the function never throws exceptions (*no-throw guarantee*).
**Otherwise, it causes undefined behavior.**

Answer (score 1):

in document of stl strings, the part regarding operator[] in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) it is mentioned that
(It is for string s, at position pos, s[pos])

> Exception safety
> If pos is not greater than the string length, the function never throws >exceptions (no-throw guarantee).
> otherwise, it causes undefined behavior.

one interesting point is that:

> If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to a >null character ('\0').(C++98)
>
> If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to >the null character that follows the last character in the string, which >shall not be modified.(C++11)

but member function ".at" is as it says in documents:

> Strong guarantee: if an exception is thrown, there are no changes in the >string.
>
> If pos is not less than the string length, an out_of_range exception is >thrown.